# How can I upload more than one file to my FTP site?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The idea is that if I selected more than one file then upload one file when, then when it finishes to upload then upload the next one and so on.

I changed the filedialoug to be able to select multi:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        this.txtUploadFile.Text = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

I can select more than one file the problem is that when using a breakpoint I see on this.txtUploadFile.Text one file only the first I selected. txtUploadFile is a textBox.

The first thing is: how can I see on the textBox(txtUploadFile) all the selected files and not only one? Or how can I get some indication that all the files I selected really selected? Maybe to show somehow in the textBox something that all files selected?

The important part is: how do I upload all the selected files one by one?

This is the button click event that starting the files uploading:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.ftpProgress1.IsBusy)
    {
        this.ftpProgress1.CancelAsync();
        this.btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
    }
    else
    {
        FtpSettings f = new FtpSettings();
        f.Host = this.txtHost.Text;
        f.Username = this.txtUsername.Text;
        f.Password = this.txtPassword.Text;
        f.TargetFolder = this.txtDir.Text;
        f.SourceFile = this.txtUploadFile.Text;
        f.Passive = this.chkPassive.Checked;
        try
        {
            f.Port = Int32.Parse(this.txtPort.Text);
        }
        catch { }
        this.toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;
        this.ftpProgress1.RunWorkerAsync(f);
        this.btnUpload.Text = "Cancel";
    }
}
```

I also have a backgroundworker with a progressBar so each file that is uploading the progressBar should show the progress of the uploading today it's showing for one file since I can upload only one file:

```
private void ftpProgress1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();    // The message will be something like: 45 Kb / 102.12 Mb
    this.toolStripProgressBar1.Value = Math.Min(this.toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum, e.ProgressPercentage);
}

private void ftpProgress1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString(), "FTP error");
    else if(e.Cancelled)
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Upload Cancelled";
    else
        this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Upload Complete";
    this.btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
    this.toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;
}
```

And last the class of the FTP uploader:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace FTP_ProgressBar
{
    public partial class FtpProgress : BackgroundWorker
    {
        public static string ConnectionError;
        private FtpSettings f;

        public FtpProgress()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public FtpProgress(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FtpProgress_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                f = e.Argument as FtpSettings;
                string UploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", f.Host, f.TargetFolder == "" ? "" : f.TargetFolder + "/", Path.GetFileName(f.SourceFile));
                if (!UploadPath.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
                    UploadPath = "ftp://" + UploadPath;
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadPath);
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.UsePassive = f.Passive;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Timeout = 300000;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
                long FileSize = new FileInfo(f.SourceFile).Length;
                string FileSizeDescription = GetFileSize(FileSize);
                int ChunkSize = 4096, NumRetries = 0, MaxRetries = 50;
                long SentBytes = 0;
                byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(f.SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        int BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                        while (BytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (bw.CancellationPending)
                                    return;

                                requestStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead);

                                SentBytes += BytesRead;

                                string SummaryText = String.Format("Transferred {0} / {1}", GetFileSize(SentBytes), FileSizeDescription);
                                bw.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)SentBytes / (decimal)FileSize) * 100), SummaryText);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                                if (NumRetries++ < MaxRetries)
                                {
                                    fs.Position -= BytesRead;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Error occurred during upload, too many retries. \n{0}", ex.ToString()));
                                }
                            }
                            BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                        }
                    }
                }
                using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Status)
                {
                    case WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure:
                        ConnectionError = "Error: Please check the ftp address";
                        break;
                    case WebExceptionStatus.Timeout:
                        ConnectionError = "Error: Timout Request";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public static string GetFileSize(long numBytes)
        {
            string fileSize = "";

            if(numBytes > 1073741824)
                fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.00} Gb", (double)numBytes / 1073741824);
            else if(numBytes > 1048576)
                fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.00} Mb", (double)numBytes / 1048576);
            else
                fileSize = String.Format("{0:0} Kb", (double)numBytes / 1024);

            if(fileSize == "0 Kb")
                fileSize = "1 Kb";
            return fileSize;
        }
    }

    public class FtpSettings
    {
        public string Host, Username, Password, TargetFolder, SourceFile;
        public bool Passive;
        public int Port = 21;
    }
}
```

It is a bit long, but I couldn't find a way to narrow the code since it's all connected to each other.

What I need it to do is if I selected more than one file make something like a queue and automatic upload one file when finished upload the next file and so on until the last file.

Today I can upload only one file. Single file each time.
I need that it will automatically upload all the selected files. Using the progressBar and the backgroundworker like it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a procedure how to upload multiple files from the directory where ftp - an address of ftp server:

```
    private void uploadFTP(DirectoryInfo d, string ftp)
    {
        FileInfo[] flist = d.GetFiles();
        if (flist.GetLength(0) > 0)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo txf in flist)
            {
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftp + txf.Name);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = false;

                FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(txf.FullName);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                stream.Close();

                Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                reqStream.Close();

                txf.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
```

And iterate on those elements to upload them one by one.

[FileNames Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames(v=vs.80).aspx)